# How to make Internet Information Services (IIS) Support SSE (Server Sent Events)?

Tags: iis, server, server-sent-events

I have implemented SSE Server in python Django. When the SSE application runs in the django development environment, everything works fine. When a push event occurs on the server, the message is pushed to the browser in real time and EventSource can get the message without delay.

However,  when I try to run the exact same under IIS, the output is blocked, no longer real-time push. Only when all the messages are completed, the server merges all the messages together and push them to the browser in a single response. This happens even when using Localhost requests, so I don't think this is caused by a proxy or firewall. (I use：IIS+Django+wfastcgi)

here is my code：

```
import time,datetime
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def sse_stream(request):
    
    def event_stream():
        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(1)
            yield f"data: Event {i}:{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}\n\n"
        yield "event: close\ndata: \n\n"

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    return response
```

I have tried entirely disabling IIS cache and the dynamic compression, but the problem is still not resolved. (Even "Dynamic Content compression" module is not installed)

```
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />
        <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Talk to your network team to see if there are additional devices between the internet and your IIS. Load balancers, Cloudflare, etc. can all buffer responses.